# Is there any way to add a starting of link to a unknown m3u8 file

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace, m3u8

I recently wrote a code which uses `file_get_contents` along with some `USER_AGENT` headers and other headers to get a source of a `m3u8` file , when echoed it looks like following

```
#EXTM3U #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE,RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=25.000,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2",AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1500000,BANDWIDTH=1870000 tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8?token=XYZ_YIE2kpAL6yriswpbrwGAvA%3D%3D%2C1608554743.5691007667
```

Now I wrote a code to add
`http://example.com/mono.php?`
to the url (tracks-v1a1 one )
The code which I wrote is

```
$test_value = str_replace('tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8?token=' . "(*^\)", "http://example.com/mono.php/tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8?token=" . "-1/", $hs2);
```

I tried using `preg_replace` too but was unsuccessful, can anyone please find out my mistake.

EDITED
According to the The Fourth Bird Sir's link and code
The following code worked like a charm

```
<?php

$hs2 = '#EXTM3U #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE,RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=25.000,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2",AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1500000,BANDWIDTH=1870000 tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8?token=XYZ_YIE2kpAL6yriswpbrwGAvA%3D%3D%2C1608554743.5691007667';
$pattern = "~tracks-v1a1/mono\.m3u8\?token=\S+~";
$replacement = "http://example.com/mono.php?$0";
$test_value = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $hs2);

echo $test_value;
```

Thanks a lot 'The Fourth Bird ' Sir ,

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://3v4l.org/PZgli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
$hs2 = '#EXTM3U #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE,RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=25.000,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2",AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1500000,BANDWIDTH=1870000 tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8?token=XYZ_YIE2kpAL6yriswpbrwGAvA%3D%3D%2C1608554743.5691007667';
$pattern = "~tracks-v1a1/mono\.m3u8\?token=\S+~";
$replacement = "http://example.com/mono.php?$0";
$test_value = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $hs2);

echo $test_value;
```

Output

```
#EXTM3U #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE,RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=25.000,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2",AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1500000,BANDWIDTH=1870000 http://example.com/mono.php?tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8?token=XYZ_YIE2kpAL6yriswpbrwGAvA%3D%3D%2C1608554743.5691007667
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/PZgli)